# How to properly clear content of specific columns in a table (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

The table I'm working with has about 40k rows and the data I want to clear are in the first 15 columns, so I have code it the following to do the job:

```
Sub DeleteOperationsTable()
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 1 To 15
    (*) Sheet(1).ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.Clear
   Next i
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It happens that only the columns 1 to 7 are cleared.

So to debug the problem I've set a breakpoint (*) and it seems that it enters in an infinite loop. After the 7th iteration the sub start again from the beginning.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: You should not had edited you the original question with the answer. Please revert to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess! :) You have events in the worksheet, which is calling the `DeleteOpertationsTable()` by change of the worksheet.

If you disable the events through `Application.EnableEvents = False` your code should work. I have tried this and it was ok:

```
For i = 1 To 15
    Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.Clear
Next i
```

Comment: Strange things happens, I've modified the code as you can see on the original post. Now it iterates through the 15 columns but, after el 15th iteration, the sub starts again.

The sub is only asigned to a button, and there are no events on the document.

Comment: @giorgiline - that is strange, true. What happens if you write `DeleteOperationsTable` in the immediate window and press Enter?